# CXF EndPointImpl How to set a timeout in published endpoint

Tags: web-services, soap, wsdl, timeout, cxf

Sorry if my qestion is not really clear, it's difficult to explain my problem.

So, I use the CXF framework for the first time. I searched a solution on web without success. Let's explain the use case.

I try to write a Web Service ( in server mode ) to receive SOAP messages, handle processing and answer. To do that I use CXF with WSDL first approach.

My implementation seems working well, I receive SOAP message through my implemented class with annotation "@webservice".... process this request and return an answer.
My issue is located on processsing side, somethinme , and depending on the SOAP message , it cna be very long and in that case  CXF handle a timeout.
So, I would like to configure the "timeout" which allow me to make this long processing

```
    EndpointImpl jaxWsEndpoint = (EndpointImpl) Endpoint.publish(endPointAddress, httpWebService);
```

the object **httpWebService** represent the *"callback"* class.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ReceiveTimeout` at configuration level to set the length of time in milliseconds your service attempts to receive a request before the connection times out. Set 0 for no timeout

```
  <http-conf:destination name="{http://apache.org/hello_world_soap_http}SoapPort.http-destination">
       <http-conf:server ReceiveTimeout="0" />
  </http-conf:destination>
```

Take in account that connection timeout parameters also can be set in you application server configuration

Comment: Hi @BrK, have you checked it?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to follow the [official way](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/configuration.html) (depends on Spring), you can try this:

```
EndpointImpl ep = (EndpointImpl) endpoint;
JettyHTTPDestination dest = (JettyHTTPDestination) ep.getServer().getDestination();
JettyHTTPServerEngine se = (JettyHTTPServerEngine) dest.getEngine();
AbstractConnector ac = (AbstractConnector) se.getConnector();
ac.setIdleTimeout(0);
```

Comment: Sory for the delay, unfortunatly it does not work .. :(